# Python - Instantiating a class inside a dictionary

Tags: python

calibrate.py

```
class FullDirichletCalibrator(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):
    def __init__(self, reg_lambda_list=0.0):
        self.reg_lambda = reg_lambda_list
```

test_code.py

```
from .calibrate import FullDirichletCalibrator

DIRICHLET_CALIBRATE = 'test'
CALIBRATION_METHODS = dict({DIRICHLET_CALIBRATE: FullDirichletCalibrator})

calibrator = CALIBRATION_METHODS[DIRICHLET_CALIBRATE](reg_lambda_list=reg_list)
```

So I have a dictionary of classes (or will eventually be plural) and I'm trying to get the class from the dict then instantiate it with parameters, but when I try to instantiate it I get the following and I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'FullDirichletCalibrator' object has no attribute 'reg_lambda_list'
```

**How do I instantiate a class from a dictionary?**

Comment: I think your problem is not within the code snippet you posted. The idea itself should work (including instantiating the object as you outlined). It seems that somewhere else you use your object and access the `reg_lambda_list`  attribute instead of the `reg_lambda` as you named it within the class.

Answer (score 0):

shrug, use a lambda.
You probably want to refactor your code if you are relying on this construct.

```
CALIBRATION_METHODS = dict({DIRICHLET_CALIBRATE: lambda x: FullDirichletCalibrator(*x)})
calibrator = CALIBRATION_METHODS[DIRICHLET_CALIBRATE](reg_list)
```

Comment: how would you suggest writing? The user can pass a string and that'll call a class, but the string has to be a list with a corresponding class.